# Capture Touch on Sprite using RayCast in case of Multiple Cameras

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have two cameras in my Hirearchy one is named "Main Camera" & other is "ABC_Camera". I have sprites with colliders applied on them and I am trying to get click on Sprites through this code:

```
if (Physics.Raycast (ray,out hit,1000)) {
    colliderName = hit.transform.name;
    hit.transform.SendMessage ("Selected");
}
```

This code is working fine in case of Main Camera .But once camera is changed from Main Camera to ABC_Camera, above mentioned if condition does not work. Here is the code I am using to switch cameras:

```
Camera cam1= GameObject.Find("ABC_Camera").GetComponent<Camera>();
cam1.enabled = true;
```

Please help me.

Comment: What have you set var ray as?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(touch.position.x,touch.position.y,0f);
          Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (v3);

Comment: You're enabling your camera but still using "Camera.main" on your RayCast. Change the var ray to cam1 when you enable it.

Comment: Yes you are right..I change it to Camera.current. Now It is working.Thanks for your help...:)

Comment: I've added it as an answer, please accept it as the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're enabling your camera but still using "Camera.main" on your RayCast. Change the var ray to cam1 when you enable it.